# Process killed when loading INSTRUCTOR_Tfransformer (HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings)

Tags: langchain, large-language-model

I'am trying to build this simple app , where I try to provide context to my LLM app.

The idea is to import PDF's and provide them as context to the LLM.

I'am using langchain (textsplitter , embedding and vectorstore), but I'am having some issues running the program on my computer. Particularly when turning the text chunks into embeddings to store them in vector store the process will be killed :

```
def get_vectorstore(text_chunks):
    embeddings = HuggingFaceInstructEmbeddings(model_name="hkunlp/instructor-xl")
    vectorstore = FAISS.from_texts(texts=text_chunks, embedding=embeddings)
    return vectorstore



load INSTRUCTOR_Transformer
Killed
```

I'am wondering if this is my PC problem or if it could be anything else..

Comment: You probably run out of memory. Have you ever monitored it while executing?